# Alert Dialog how do i recheck if there is an internet connection

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i have an alert dialog box, which shows a message to users if there is no internet connection detected on the phone. How do i check and retry if there is an internet connection and if there is still no connection the dialog box will appear again?

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
private ProgressBar mProgress;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    if (Internet()) {
        splash();
    } else {
        showAlertDialog(Splash.this, "No Internet Access",
                "No Internet Connection detected", false);
    }
}

public void splash() {
    mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
    mProgress.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
            Color.BLUE, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    Thread timerTread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                prog();

                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Games.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    timerTread.start();
}
private void prog() {
    for (int progress = 0; progress <= 100; progress += 20) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            mProgress.setProgress(progress);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public boolean Internet() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }

    }
    return false;
}

public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Retry ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

    }
});
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Exit ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();


}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you use a Broadcast receiver for continuous check for connection, instead of making buttons ?

Answer (score 1):

```
     public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.positiveText("Retry");
        alertDialog.negativeText("Cancel");
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Overrite your Method and add to the Dialog a "positiveText" and a "negativeText". After that you can call the "onPositive"-Method where you can try again if there is a Internet-Connection.

For more Information visit this site: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this..

```
class Splash extends Activity {
    private ProgressBar mProgress;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        checkAndStartActivity();
    }

    public void checkAndStartActivity(
    if (isWorkingInternetPersent()) {
            splash();
        } else {
            showAlertDialog(Splash.this, "No Internet Access",
                    "No Internet Connection detected", false);
        }
    }


    public void splash() {
        mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        mProgress.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
                Color.BLUE, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        Thread timerTread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    prog();

                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Games.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        timerTread.start();
    }
    private void prog() {
        for (int progress = 0; progress <= 100; progress += 20) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                mProgress.setProgress(progress);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isWorkingInternetPersent() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivityManager != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }

        }
        return false;
    }

    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
       AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
       adb.setView(alertDialogView);
       adb.setTitle(title);

       adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          checkAndStartActivity();
       } });
       adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener({
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         Splash.this.finish();
       } });
       adb.show();

    }
```